# In Node-RED Dashboard problems with *ngFor directive

Tags: angular, dashboard, ngfor, node-red

The goal is to iterate over an array of strings of unknown length and display its data in a Node-RED Dashboard. The problem I'm facing is that the Dashboard displays the length of the array, and also the content of it at a specific index, but the `*ngFor` directive is not working as expected.

[image: Node-RED flow]

The code in the function is:

```
msg.payload = [ "here","second","curazao" ];
console.log(msg)
return msg;
```

The array is ok in the `console.log`:

[image: console.log]

And the template block has this code:

```
<p>lenght is working</p>
<div>{{msg.payload.length}}</div>

<p>msg.payload[0] is working</p>
<ul>
  <li>{{msg.payload[0]}}</li>
  <li>{{msg.payload[1]}}</li>
  <li>{{msg.payload[2]}}</li>
</ul>

<p>*ngFor is not working</p>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let element of msg.payload">{{element}}</li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that I cant make the *ngFor to work, here is how is rendered:

[image: Dashboard]

Most likely the problem is in the way I'm using the `*ngFor` directive.

Comment: "The code in the function is: ..." Where is this logic called? Does this happen during `ngOnInit` or somewhere else?

Comment: Hi @PMO1948, this is a Node-red project, so is not a normal angular project, meaning that I don't have the folders and files like in a regular project. If you see the first picture, you will see a orange block called "function" (which is triggered when I click on the "timestamp" block), here is my code. Let me know if this explains what you are asking.

Comment: Got it. I am not familiar with NODE-RED, but hopefully someone else will be able to help!

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I've stumbled on a similar issue and found a solution.

Looks like the right way to do this is by using the `ng-repeat` directive, as such:

```
<p>Try with ng-repeat</p>
<ul ng-repeat="element in msg.payload">
  <li>{{element}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I've tested this on Node-Red v2.1.4 and it works as expected.

Source: http://noderedguide.com/tutorial-node-red-dashboards-creating-your-own-ui-widget/

Comment: Note the need to change "**let** element **of** msg.payload" to "element **in** msg.payload" as shown.